# AWK command to read value from JSON

Tags: regex, awk

I want to read a value using AWK command from below json by giving the key name as input,

```
"[{\"key\":\"ResourceClass\",\"value\":\"SingleNode\"},{\"key\":\"Vendor\",\"value\":\"AWS\"},{\"key\":\"Creator\",\"value\":\"ea35b938-c575-41d3-8705\"},{\"key\":\"ClusterName\",\"value\":\"cluster-Offer\"},{\"key\":\"ClusterId\",\"value\":\"056-987-656\"},{\"key\":\"JobId\",\"value\":\"1323\"},{\"key\":\"RunName\",\"value\":\"OfferDataProcess\"}]"
```

Expected output for a given key

```
"RunName"
OfferDataProcess
```

Answer (score 1):

Your source is not correct JSON.

Since AWK does not understand JSON, you too should stop seeing JSON as that. See it as a string.

Something like this will get the desired result for the specific example

```
BEGIN{
  FS="{"
  key="RunName"

}
{
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){
    if ($i~key) {
      mykey=$i

      # ----- first variant ------ correct json
      # match on    "value":"mystringhere"
      c=match(mykey, /"value":"([^"]*)/, arr)
      if (c>1){
        print "\""key"\""
        print arr[1]
      }

      # ----- second variant ----- quoted json
      # match on   \"value\":\"mystringhere\"
      c=match(mykey, /\\"value\\":\\"([^\\]*)/, aq)
      if (c>1){
        print "\""key"\""
        print aq[1]
      }
     } # if
    } #forloop
} #actions
```